# QDateTime custom format escaping symbols

Tags: qt, qdatetime

I would like to get a customized [QDateTime](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html) such as:

```
QString string = "23 April 2012 at 22:51";
QString format = "d MMMM yyyy at hh:mm";
```

I am unable to as the literal `at` is not recognized as an 'additional' string but has tokens associated.

- `a` ->  AM or PM
- `t` -> timezone information.

Naturally I would take an approach such as an alternative:

```
QDateTime timeNow = QDateTime::currentDateTime();

QString time1Format = "d MMMM yyyy";
QString time2Format = "hh:mm";

QString time1 = timeNow.toString(time1Format);
QString time2 = timeNow.toString(time2Format);

QString timeConcat = QString(time1 + " at " + time2);

qDebug() << "Time = " << timeConcat;
```

How can I *escape* the 'at' keyword in my format?

ap or a Interpret as an AM/PM time. ap must be either "am" or "pm".

Answer (score 4):

You must enclose the `at` string inside single quotes:

> Any sequence of characters enclosed in single quotes will be included
>   verbatim in the output string (stripped of the quotes), even if it
>   contains formatting characters. Two consecutive single quotes ("''")
>   are replaced by a single quote in the output. All other characters in
>   the format string are included verbatim in the output string.

```
qDebug() << "Time = " << QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("d MMMM yyyy 'at' hh::mm");
```